# Child expanding out of parent

Tags: html, css

I have some divs within a main_content div, but they do not slot in within their parent.

I have done my research and I have tried to float: left the parent, but unfortunately it ruins the curved edges and shadow, so something is clearly wrong.

Within the child divs I have a checkbox which when ticked, expands a panel of text, but the same issue is occuring whereby the divdoes not increase in size, it is being considered a seperate entity from what shouldbe it's child.

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aNgVj/

Here is the html

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main_content">
        <h1 class="standard">Team Directory</h1>
        <div class="plaque_left">
            <h2>Blackhawks</h2>
            <h3>EB Netball CLub</h3>
            <p>www.random.com</p>
            <p>More text</p>
            <p>and more...</p>
            <p>and more</p>
            <p>finally...</p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="show" id="show"/>
                <label for="show">Named Players</label>
                <article class="small">More content here
                    <br/>
                        <br/>and here
                        <br/>end
                </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the linked CSS

```
#wrapper {
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    width: 77em;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 2px solid white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px black
}
#main_content {
    background: white;
    position:relative;
    width: 76em;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}
```

and (just the left divs as code is the same for the right divs, other than float:right)

```
.plaque_left {
    display:block;
    height: 23.5em;
    margin: 1em 1em 1em 5em;
    padding: 0 1em 0 1em;
    background: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10pt grey;
    float:left;
    width:38%;
    -webkit-border-radius:10pt
}
.plaque_left article {
    background:#d0a9f5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10pt;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:10;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out
}
.plaque_left input:checked ~ article {
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out
}
.plaque_left input:checked ~ article.small {
    height: 140px;
    position:relative
}
```

To confirm, the first issue is  that the `.plaque` divs are not being contained by the `#main_content` div. Secondly when the checkbox expands to show the extra content, it spills outdie of the plaque div, unless I select auto which means I can scroll, but this is notwhat I am looking for, I want the plaque div to resize to allow for the expanded content.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you put this into jsfiddle or show us what's happening?

Comment: jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aNgVj/

Comment: Is there a reason you are using relative positioning? At first glance it doesn't seem like you need to use it. Typically you only want to use relative positioning when you are absolutely positioning other elements inside of it. Try removing the relative positioning and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: [jsFiddle with formatted code](http://jsfiddle.net/9gSEX/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you add `overflow: hidden` to the `#wrapper`:

```
#wrapper {overflow: hidden;}
```

That's the easiest way to force the wrapper to enclose the floated items.

Comment: It fixes the problem as I understand it. I'd rather hear back from the OP on this.

Comment: "I want the plaque div to resize to allow for the expanded content", seems like this hides it...

Comment: This would hide content that overflows the div - while it would contain floats, it's not actually doing anything to allow for adjustable heights.

Comment: Ah, right. Removing the height from `.plaque_left` will fix that.

Comment: ralph.m solved the first problem, and helion3 solved the expansion problem. thank you both

Answer (score 2):

The `plaque_left` div isn't expanding in height because you have it fixed: `height: 23.5em;`. You can use `min-height` or remove the height entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Add an element such as a div which will clear the floats and keep them from collapsing. You can use this style:

```
.clearFloat{
    clear: both;
}
```

Then you can create an empty div at the bottom of your main content, that will clear (make room for) any elements above it. You can see the behavior in the fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/aNgVj/1/

Comment: It's better to use CSS to solve a CSS issue rather than add extra, non-semantic HTML elements. :-) `overflow: hidden;` is the easiest solution, and is fine as long as you don't need elements (such as absolutely positioned ones) to hang outside of the container.

Comment: Ahh, just saw what happens with the checkbox. You would need to remove the height from .plaque_left as well, just as stated above.